# Only sending content to a variable if _POST is filled in

Tags: php, variables, if-statement, conditional-statements, isset

Help! I'm having some trouble getting some conditional statements into my php script for a form.

This is gist of the HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="address1" id="address1" class="required" />
<input type="text" name="address2" id="address2" />
<input type="text" name="city" id="city" />
<input type="text" name="postcode" id="postcode" class="required" />
```

And the php looks a bit like this:

```
$address1 = $_REQUEST["address1"] ;
$address2 = $_REQUEST["address2"] ;
$city = $_REQUEST["city"] ;
$postcode = $_REQUEST["postcode"] ;

$message = 
"address: $address1, " .
"$address2, " .
"$city, " .
"$postcode" .

$sent = mail($to, $subject, $message, 'From:' . $email_address) ;
```

I've got some jQuery validation on 'address1' and 'postcode' so they're not an issue as they'll always return a value. If 'address2' and 'city' aren't filled in (maybe the form-filler doesn't have a second line to their address, or doesn't put the city in as they think -rightly - that the postcode will be sufficient in finding their address) they still return a value (of 'nothing') on the email.

What I would like to happen is for the form inputs that are left blank to email nothing at all. In other words, if the $address2 variable is empty, don't send me the "blank space". For example, if it's all complete I'd get this, which is great:

*address: 1 Test Street, West End, Test City, AB1 23C*

If there's a field missing I'd get this, which is a bit messy:

*address: 1 Test Street, , Test City, AB1 23C*

But I'd like this, because it's nice and tidy:

*address: 1 Test Street, Test City, AB1 23C*

I've been trying to get my head around the isset function but haven't had any luck. I've also tried a basic 'if' statement but can't seem to get anywhere with that either. I must admit, php isn't my strong point and I've spent a lot of time on this with no success. Your help is very much appreciated!

Many thanks,

Martin.

Comment: Your code appears to be vulnerable to email header injection. Also: `"I've got some jQuery validation on 'address1' and 'postcode' so they're not an issue as they'll always return a value."` You cannot trust client-side validation to work as you wish it to - the user can bypass it or craft their own form if they so wish.

Comment: You can get around it if you use the client side to display the form in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this kind of "parameters filtering" problematic i like to use PHP array functions.

For example:

```
<?php
$aMessage = array();

$aMessage[] = $_REQUEST["address1"] ;
$aMessage[] = $_REQUEST["address2"] ;
$aMessage[] = $_REQUEST["city"]     ;
$aMessage[] = $_REQUEST["postcode"] ;

$aMessage = array_filter($aMessage);

$message = (implode(', ', $aMessage));

echo $message;
?>
```

What it does:

1. fill the array with the differents
   parameters.
2. delete the empty values
   with the `array_filter` function
3. print the values concatenated with a
   comma (`implode` function).

With this method the code remains easy to read even if you have a lot of parameters.

Comment: Thanks Guillaume- that works perfectly! Is it possible to do this with only 1 variable? ie. if I have a box that isn't part of a group, like the address is, and it may or may not be filled in. If it is, I need to see the contents on the email, if it isn't I don't want anything to show on the email.

Answer (score 0):

define a new php variable before importing to db

```
$address=$_REQUEST["address1"];

if (trim($_REQUEST["address2"]!=''))
$address.=','.$_REQUEST["address2"]
```

Answer (score 0):

isset() returns true if the variable *has been set* - i.e., that is has been *declared* and has a *non-NULL* value. Apart from that bit about NULL, isset() says nothing about the *contents* of that variable.

To test if a variable is truly empty (an empty string, NULL, FALSE, 0, an empty array, etc), use the aptly named empty() :)

Example:

```
$a = NULL;
$b = '';
// $c we won't declare
echo isset($a); // False - $a has a NULL value
echo isset($b); // True - $b is set to a non-NULL Value. empty() will return True too.
echo isset($c); // False - $c is not set.
```

Another way of doing what Captain mentioned above:

```
$address = "";
foreach( array( "address1", "address2", "address3" ) as $param )
{
    $param = trim($_REQUEST[$param]);
    $address .= !empty( $param ) ? ', '.$param : "";
}
```

The way this works:

1. Define the names of the elements in
   the $_REQUEST array you want.
2. You loop through each element, pull
   its value out of $_REQUEST, strip
   any straggling whitespace (with
   trim()).
3. If the parameter is not empty,
   append it to $address.
4. If it is empty, you append an empty
   string.

If you haven't seen it before, that `condition ? expr_if_true : expr_if_false` syntax is called the *ternary operator*.

A tiny bit cleaner, IMO. Fewer if/else statements running around.

Comment: And as mentioned above by Hammerite, sanitise this input before you inject it into a mail() call (or put it into a DB, or print it back to screen, etc). Always assume that any and all input coming from the client is evil.

Comment: Your alternative to captain's code seems to do the trick. The only issue is that the comma that separates the array items appears before every item, meaning there's a comma before 'address1'. Would an implode function change that?

Comment: or maybe taking 'address1' out of the array and concatenating it with 'address'?